# Hide Parent Fragment from the Fragment in the viewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment A holds a view pager that display serval nested fragments. B and C are the fragments directly hold by the view pager. And each B and C holds a listView. When click listView item fragment D will show up. The problem is that, I could only hide the Fragment C and B from the viewPager, which means Fragment D will come over Fragment A. The question is how could I hide Fragment A from B and C not just hide the Fragment B and C from the viewPager.

here is the code of Fragment A

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private DisplayMetrics dm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
    dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    setTabsValue();
    initView();

    return view;

}

private void initView() {
    TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_content_text);
    titleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    titleView.setText(getString(R.string.label_alert));
}


public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    private final String[] titles = { "B", "C" };

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if (BFrag == null) {
                    BFrag = new BFrag();
                }
                return BFrag;
            case 1:
                if (CFrag == null) {
                    CFrag = new CFrag();
                }
                return CFrag;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

here is the code in Fragment B that trying to show fragment D:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
            if (pos < Item.size()) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.hide(BFrag.this);
                    DFrag dFrag = new DFrag();
                    activity.dFeedFrag = dFrag;
                    transaction.add(R.id.home_frame_content, dFeedFrag, "dFrag");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

The layout file of Fragment A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/inculde_title_bar"/>

<com.example.blah.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
```

Anyone could help me, Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because B, C is hosted in the ViewPager, so they are in the fragment A, so you just need to find fragment A and hide it.

The real question is, where is the id `home_frame_content`.

If this id is in Fragment A, D will be hidden once A is hidden. I think this is what you want.

So the id `home_frame_content` must be somewhere not in A. Then you can find A, hide it, you will get what you want.

**update 1**

And there is a demo: https://github.com/liaohuqiu/ABCDFragment

Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: nice. Everyting works fine now. Thanks for your demo! Great help with my issue.

Comment: Maybe you want to try change: transaction.add(R.id.home_frame_content, dFeedFrag, "dFrag");  -> transaction.replace(R.id.home_frame_content, dFeedFrag, "dFrag");